# C# DataGridView Refresh on Specified Interval

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a best practice question. I'm building a Windows forms application in C#/.NET 4.0 where "scans" will take place behind the scenes every X seconds and update a database. I'd like to a DataGridView refresh on a specified interval to reflect the data that is now represented in the database. I plan on doing this by adding a timer to the form and on the tick event, just re-populate the DataGridView. I was wondering if this approach is the best method or if there is a more recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

For datagridview refresh on specified interval use multithreading with delegate.Its better for memory management.

[check this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/48cfdff6%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you use an MVVM pattern an bind your datagrid data source to a collection wich raise property changed every time it's changed (Mode = TwoWay) Your data grid will be updated automatically...

```
    private ObservableCollection<Data>_dataCollection ;
    public ObservableCollection<Data> DataCollection 
    {
        get { return _dataCollection ; }
        set
        {
            _dataCollection = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("DataCollection ");
        }
    }
```

And the XAML code is :

```
     <DataGrid DataSource="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=DataCollection}"
               DataContext="YourViewModel">
```